# How do you compare enum to int?

Tags: java, enums

I am trying to change the color by using an enum, I am comparing an enum to an int but it keeps throwing an error

```
public class Game {

public enum State{
    RED, YELLOW, BLANK;
}

public State getState(int x, int y) {
    y=1;
    for (x=5;x>0;x--) {
  if (x== BLANK && y== BLANK) {
        return State.RED;
    }
    //return State.BLANK;
}
    return State.BLANK;
}
```

How do I compare an int to an enum? so that I can change the color in the first column y which is set to 1

Comment: you don't. you have to compare enums with enums. but you can add some int to your enum

Comment: Why would you *want* to? They *have* an int value, but why do you want to work around the safety they provide?

Comment: Passing parameters `x` and `y` and setting `y` to `1` and decrementing `x`... Honestly: what are you doing in your method?!

Comment: Why are you comparing coordinates to enum values? It sounds like what you ought to do is make an array of the enum type and compare against the value in the array at that x/y position. What you're currently doing doesn't make any sense. Hence the error.

Comment: I down voted because this question is not finished and does not make sense, interesting how normal questions gets closed so easily but this one survived without correction.

Comment: Rolled back because the code in the question provides specifics that make the answers make sense.

Answer (score 8):

Just use the [Enum.ordinal()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal%28%29) method of an enum to get the ordered number from 0 to X which you can compare to your `x` variable:

```
public class Game {
    public enum State {
        BLANK,   // 0
        RED,     // 1
        YELLOW   // 2
    }

    public State getState(int x, int y) {
        y = 1;
        for (x = 5; x > 0; x--) {
            if (x == State.BLANK.ordinal() && y == State.BLANK.ordinal()) {
                return State.RED;
            }
            //return State.BLANK;
        }
        return State.BLANK;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would not recommend this solution, because if you change the order or add or remove elements to the enum later, you are f*ed.

Comment: Yes, I agree! The point is, that the OPs code doesn't even make sense at all. So, I'm not sure which solution fits the best for the OPs real problem. Just wanted to show up another possibility.

Answer (score 7):

You have to assign values to the enum. As is, it's trying to compare two things which aren't comparable.

```
public class Game {

public enum State{
    RED(1), YELLOW(2), BLANK(0);

    private int val;

    private State(int value){
        val = value;
    }

    public int getValue(){
        return val;
    }
}

public State getState(int x, int y) {
    y=1;
    for (x=5;x>0;x--) {
        if (x== State.BLANK.getValue() && y== State.BLANK.getValue()) {
            return State.RED;
        }
        //return State.BLANK;
    }
    return State.BLANK;
}
}
```

Comment: This code will do what you wanted, though I honestly don't see why you would want to.

Comment: @Leo thanks, didn't catch the positioning of where I had my State's code.

Comment: @Leo Very, very slow morning :| Thank you :)

Comment: i think you could make method getState static and move it to State

Answer (score 4):

you could use `ordinal()`. It returns the ordinal of this enumeration constant (its position in its enum declaration, where the initial constant is assigned an ordinal of zero).

In your case `RED.ordinal()` would return 0.